# How to make a key toggle itself down and up with AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

The goal of my hotkey is to make tab similar to caps lock in that it toggles whether a key is being held down or not, except rather then toggling shift I need it to toggle itself. When I was trying to find the source of the problem it worked when I replaced the hotkey with something other than tab.

Here's what I have so far

```
n = 1
~$*Tab::
{
    if n = 1
    {
        n = 0
        Send {Tab down}
    } else {
        n = 1
        Send {Tab up}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your code trigger and toggle only on key release:

```
$Tab Up::
if (toggle:=!toggle) {
    Send, {Tab Down}
} else {
    Send, {Tab Up}
}
Return
```

See `UP` keyword here: http://ahkscript.org/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols